# Calculate growth rate as subtotal DAX

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot, calculation

I am having trouble calculating the weekly growth rates for a PowerPivot table.
What I am trying to do is get the week on week growth rate, meaning for example Monday vs. Monday last week. This should also apply for the grand total- calculating lets say Monday to Wednesday this week vs. same period last week (if the current week has not yet ended).

I would guess that the best way to approach this is to create a DAX formula but I am having trouble doing so and would truly appreciate your help.

Below you can find an example of the table: in this case I need the subtotal marked in gray to reflect the calculation I explained before WITHOUT changing the other values in white (above).

I would like to also mention the table is a Power Pivot table, so I cannot create a calculated field since the data behind is part of the data model.
[image]